# McCulloch-Pitts Neuron using Tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I am new to tensorflow and I am trying to implement a simple OR gate using McCulloch-Pitts Neuron using Tensorflow, and I am not able to calculate the gradients as they are returning None values.

I have tried using tape.watch(), and it did not work either, or I tried incorrectly. Any suggestions or comments are appreciated.

Thanks!

```py
import tensorflow as tf
class MCN(tf.keras.models.Model):
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.w = self.add_weight(shape=(2,), trainable=True)
    self.threshold = self.add_weight(shape=(1, ), trainable=True)

  def call(self, x):
    weighted_sum = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(self.w, x))
    return tf.cond(weighted_sum >= self.threshold, lambda: 1.0, lambda: 0.0)

data=tf.constant([[0, 0], [0, 1], [1,0], [1,1]], dtype=tf.float32)
obj = MCN()

y_h=tf.Variable([0,1,1,1], dtype=tf.float32)
y_h = tf.reshape(y_h, (-1, 1))

epochs = 5

for epoch in range(epochs):
  losses=0
  with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    for i in range(len(data)):
      preds = obj(data[i])
      ls = loss_fn(y_h[i], preds)
      losses+=ls
  grads = tape.gradient(losses, obj.trainable_variables)
  print(grads)
  # optim.apply_gradients(zip(grads, obj.trainable_variables))
```

As all gradients are of form `[None, None]`, it is raising the error

```py
ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['Variable:0', 'Variable:0'],). Provided `grads_and_vars` is ((None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(2,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([-0.964952 ,  1.0493928], dtype=float32)>), (None, <tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32, numpy=array([1.1824547], dtype=float32)>)).
```

Comment: A thresholding function is not differentiable, the gradients are undefined at the threshold and 0 everywhere else. So you cannot use such a function for gradient-based learning.